# Is there a portable way to write a CHECK constraint that checks if a TEXT value is an integer?

Tags: sql

Is there a portable way to write the CHECK below?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id2 TEXT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id1),
    CHECK ('check that id2 is positive integer')
)
```

Comment: cast as int, >= 0.

Comment: **Never** store numbers in `text` columns.

Comment: The portable way is to store the data using the correct data type.

Comment: I am aware of how how SQL data types works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no portable way of dealing with *malformed data*.

Having said that, each database has its own ways of dealing with malformed data. The typical solution is to use a regular expression in a check constraint. Other solution can try to cast the value to a numeric scalar. All these solutions work, but they have their quirks on each database.

I would suggest you fix the data type if possible. That will greatly simplify all these headaches.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct until proven otherwise :D. I've seen some examples (for PostgreSQL I think) which use regexes, but I figured they weren't portable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right datatype, `integer`, **not** `text`, and check for the values to be positive (or non negative).

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
             (id1 integer
                  NOT NULL,
              id2 integer
                  NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (id1),
              CHECK (id2 > 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @AntonLahti: It does answer the question. An appropriate data type is part of a "check" if you will. Using `text` for an integer doesn't make sense. Change your data types! It's the right thing to do and it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I didn't ask what the appropriate data type is, I asked how to write a specific check constraint in portable SQL.

Comment: Using the appropriate datatype *is* part of the answer. That you did not specifically ask  about it is true, but how should you given that you asked because you don't know the answer or part of it... You could have explained in your question why you think you cannot use `integer`. Maybe the actual problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data type of id2 integer and use constraint as below

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (id1 integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                  id2 integer NOT NULL CHECK (id2 > 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the question.